# Can a 'skinny table' design be compensated with a view?

Tags: database, database-design

Context: simple webapp game for personal learning purposes, using postgres. I can design it however I want.

2 tables 1 view (there are additional tables view references that aren't important)

```
Table: Research
col: research_id (foreign key to an outside table)
col: category (integer foreign key to category table)
col: percent (integer)
constraint (unique combination of the three columns)

Table: Category
col: category_id (primary key auto inc)
col: name(varchar(255))
```

notes: this table exists to capture the 4 categories of research I want in business logic and which I assume is not best practice to hardcode as columns in the db

```
View: Research_view
col: research_id (from research table)
col: foo1 (one of the categories from category table)
col: foo2 (etc...)
col: other cols from other joins
```

notes:has insert/update/delete statements that uses above tables appropriately

The research table itself I worry qualifies as a "Skinny Table" (hadn't heard the term until I just saw it in the Ibatis manning book). For example test data within it looks like:
`| research_id | percent | category | 

      |           1 | 25 | 1 | 

      |           1 | 25 | 2 | 

      |           1 | 25 | 3 | 

      |           1 | 25 | 4 | 

      |           2 | 20 | 1 | 

      |           2 | 30 | 2 | 

      |           2 | 25 | 3 | 

      |           2 | 25 | 4 |`

1) Does it make sense to have all columns in a table collectively define unique entries?
2) Does this 'smell' to you?

Comment: The data you have suggest that `research_id` is **not** the primary key. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ypercube correct it is not. The combination of the three columns defines a unique entry as the data shows. will edit and fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of notes to start:

> constraint (unique combination of the three columns)

It makes no sense to have a unique constraint that includes a single-column primary key.  Including that column will cause every row to be unique.

```
notes: this table exists to capture the 4 categories of research I want in business logic and which I assume is not best practice to hardcode as columns in the db
```

If a research item/entity is required to have all four categories defined for it to be valid, they should absolutely be columns in the research table.  I can't tell definitively from your statement whether this is the case or not, but your assumption is faulty if looked at in isolation.  Let your model reflect reality as closely as possible.

Another factor is whether it's a requirement that additional categories may be added to the system post-deployment.  Whether the categories are intended to be flexible vs. fixed should absolutely influence the design.

> 1) Does it make sense to have all columns in a table collectively
>   define unique entries?

I would say it's not common, but can imagine there are situations where it might be appropriate.

> 2) Does this 'smell' to you?

Hard to say without more details.

All that said, if the intent is to view and add research items with all four categories, I would say (again) that you should consider whether the four categories are semantically attributes of the research entity.

As a random example, things like height and weight might be considered categories of a person, but they would likely be stored flat on the person table, and not in a separate table.